# Vampiric Link on opponents creature

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Suppose I cast a [Vampiric Link](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVampiric%20Link%5d) on an opponents creature. Does the opponent gain life when this creature does damage or do I gain that life?

Answer (score 7):

Vampiric Link says:

> Whenever enchanted creature deals damage, you gain that much life.

"You" on a card refers to the controller of the card - and regardless of what Vampiric Link is enchanting, you (the person who cast Vampiric Link) will always* control it. So you'll always be the one gaining life, not your opponent.

*barring any control changing effects that occur

Comment: This answer is correct, but "an effect [that] causes you to exchange control of two permanents" is an oddly specific example of a control changing effect, which is potentially confusing. Is there any particular reason you singled out that kind of effect?

Comment: I agree with murgatroid99. I would either remove the note or have it say something like 'barring any control changing effects that may occur'

Comment: That's a much better way of wording that caveat. Edited.

Comment: Also note that if the card designer actually wanted the opposite, he would use the phrase "that creature's controller", not "you".

Comment: @liori Or, simply "Enchanted Creature gains Lifelink."

Comment: Thx for your replies,